# Searching and downloading pdf files contained in a pandas df column of links

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have a df with three columns `[[SerieFecha, Título, Link]]`. I want to create a loop that iterate over each link in the ['Link'] column to find and download the embedded pdf file.

I manage to do this one link at a time. But this approach is obviously not efficient.

This is what I have done so far.

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = "http://legislaturautuado.com/pgs/resolutions.php?st=5&f=2016"
r = requests.get(url)
html_table = BeautifulSoup(r.text).find('table')
r.close()
df = pd.read_html(str(html_table), header=0)[0]
df['Link'] = [link.get('href') for link in html_table.find_all('a')]
df.head()
```

[image: df]

Then I use the first link found to search for the .pdf link it contains.

```
df.iloc[0,2]
```

'http://legislaturautuado.com/pgs/docviewer.php?p=1182&pt=2&d=1-2016-2017&dt=2'

```
import urllib.request
my_url = 'http://legislaturautuado.com/pgs/docviewer.php?p=1182&pt=2&d=1-2016-2017&dt=2'
html=urllib.request.urlopen(my_url).read()
sopa = BeautifulSoup(html)
current_link = ''
for link in sopa.find_all('a'):
    current_link = link.get('href')
    if current_link.endswith('pdf'):
      print('Mi pdf: ' + current_link)
```

[output] `Mi pdf: http://legislaturautuado.com/res/1-2016-2017.pdf`

And finally I download the document with the following lines:

```
from pathlib import Path
filename = Path('first.pdf')
pdfurl = 'http://legislaturautuado.com/res/1-2016-2017.pdf'
response = requests.get(pdfurl)
filename.write_bytes(response.content)
```

I've seen several posts on similar topics but most of them already have the link to the pdf document. In my case I need to get the link to the pdf document to download it. I would appreciate any advice to help me put everything in one process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `df` you already have. Loop over the items in that column, grab the source urls of the `pdf`s and save them.

Here's how:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get("http://legislaturautuado.com/pgs/resolutions.php?st=5&f=2016").text
html_table = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser").find("table")

df = pd.read_html(str(html_table), header=0)[0]
df["Link"] = [link.get("href") for link in html_table.find_all("a")]

for link in df["Link"]:
    response = requests.get(link, "html.parser").text
    pdf_object = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser").find("object")
    pdf_url, _ = pdf_object["data"].split("#")
    print(f"Fetching {pdf_url}")
    with open(f"{pdf_url.rpartition('/')[-1]}", "wb") as f:
        f.write(requests.get(pdf_url).content)
```

This should get you all the pdf files.

Comment: `pdf_url, _ = pdf_object["data"].split("#")` is different from `pdf_url = pdf_object["data"].split("#")`. I can see that the output is different but I do not know why it happens. What does the `_` do in that line?

Comment: It's different because when you split on `#` you get a list of (in this case) two items. I don't need the second one, so I "drop" it by using `_`, which is called a blank identifier.